# Use google-ouaht-2.0 only for authentication in android app and laravel server

Tags: php, android, laravel, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am making an android app for tracking progress in premade tasks from a server.
The app will create local profiles and download the tasks from the server, and save any progress the user makes (when they tick having done sub-tasks).
What I want to do is be able to upload this progress back to the server to sync across devices.
At first I created user accounts, and a random token to authenticate against the server after initial logon, to prevent saving passwords on the client.
But then I figured I could use something like OAuth2 to login on the app with my google account, and then use the ID/email-address provided by Google to save the information on my server.

The problem is I can't figure out how to **correctly** set this up.
I could easily just login, send the email to the server and save the data on that ID.
The problem is what Google Token do I save?
What should I save on the client side and send with the API-request to authenticate later?
How / do I have to refresh the token?

All I want is a way to use OAuth from Google to authenticate the communication between the client and server...

**NB:** I am not going to use the Google OAuth for anything except auth and retrieving the users email-address.. (No Google API or anything..).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the answer you seek, but I used this solution in a recent project.

Including [this](https://github.com/adamwathan/eloquent-oauth-l5) package in your Laravel environment will make handling any OAuth provider super-easy. You create two routes - one for login and one for the OAuth callback - and everything from token to session management is handled for you.

You can specify how and what data is stored in your database by handling the callback in a certain way. Check out this code I wrote for a Facebook login scheme:

```
try {
    SocialAuth::login('facebook', function($user, $details){
        if(!$details->full_name && !$details->email && !$details->avatar){
            throw new InvalidAuthorizationCodeException();
        }
        $user->name = $details->full_name;
        $user->email = $details->email;
        $user->avatar = $details->avatar . "?type=large";
        $user->save();
    });
} catch (ApplicationRejectedException $e) {
    // User rejected application
    return view('errors.facebook');
} catch (InvalidAuthorizationCodeException $e) {
    // Authorization was attempted with invalid
    // code,likely forgery attempt
    return view('errors.facebook');
}

return Redirect::intended();
```

Finally if you want to check who is currently logged in, a simple `$user = Auth::user();` will suffice. You can then use an id you have set in your database for user identification, if you make sure your API is protected by the Laravel auth middleware.